# SVN does not see my file permission changes

Tags: macos, svn

I am working on a android project, I am doing chmod 777 gradlew to make it executable. But the SVN does not think gradlew file is changed. How can I make SVN see my changes. I am using version svn client for mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion does not manage filesystem permission bits with one exception, and that is the executable bit. However, it does not track it directly via the filesystem permissions. Instead, it uses its own property and then the appropriate filesystem attributes are set based on the platform your client is running on.

To tell Subversion that a file is executable, set the property `svn:executable` on that file - `svn propset svn:executable on <filename>`